# How to get all locked fields on form

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I am using `Dynamics crm 2016`,I lock and unlock my fields in different stages of my form, I need to keep that some fields will stay locked all the time, for that reason I need the option to get all locked fields and to avoid unlocking them, how do I get all fields that are locked as default, how can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a method to get that information:

```
var isDisabled = Xrm.Page.getControl(arg).getDisabled()
```

So you can simply iterate over `Xrm.Page.ui.controls` to get all locked fields:

```
function getAllLockedFields(){
    var lockedFields = new Array();
    Xrm.Page.ui.controls.forEach(function(control, index){
         if(control.getDisabled()){
             lockedFields.push(control);
         }
    });

    return lockedFields;
}
```

For Dynamics 365 9.0 you should use `formContext` from `executionContext` instead of deprecated `Xrm.Page`